# Use data from API in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a small frontend application with react where I want to display data that I fetch from an API and put it in the state. But when I try to acces that data for displaying it (or log it to the console) I get undefined. It seems like I try to use the data before the call is done, but I dont get how I can change that.

This is my code for the Component that makes my API call

```
import Search from '../Components/Search';
import '../App.css';

export default function People () {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
      
        fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people')
        .then(res => 
            res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setData(data);
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error)); 
    }, [])
    
    console.log(data["results"]);
    
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container-column">
                <div className="item">
                    <Search />
                </div>
                {isLoading && <p>Wait I'm Loading data for you</p>}
                render the data here {data["count"]};
            </div>
            
            
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

The data I get from the API looks like this:

```
    "count": 82,
    "next": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker",
            "height": "172",
            "mass": "77",
            "hair_color": "blond",
            "skin_color": "fair",
            "eye_color": "blue",
            "birth_year": "19BBY",
            "gender": "male",
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ],
            "species": [],
            "vehicles": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/14/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/"
            ],
            "starships": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/12/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/22/"
            ],
            "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z",
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/"
        },
        {
            "name": "C-3PO",
            "height": "167",
            "mass": "75",
            "hair_color": "n/a",
            "skin_color": "gold",
            "eye_color": "yellow",
            "birth_year": "112BBY",
            "gender": "n/a",
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/4/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ],
            "species": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/species/2/"
            ],
            "vehicles": [],
            "starships": [],
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:10:51.357000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.309000Z",
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/"
        },
        {
            "name": "R2-D2",
            "height": "96",
            "mass": "32",
            "hair_color": "n/a",
            "skin_color": "white, blue",
            "eye_color": "red",
            "birth_year": "33BBY",
            "gender": "n/a",
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/8/",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/4/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ],
            "species": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/species/2/"
            ],
            "vehicles": [],
            "starships": [],
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:11:50.376000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.311000Z",
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/3/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Darth Vader",
            "height": "202",
            "mass": "136",
            "hair_color": "none",
            "skin_color": "white",
            "eye_color": "yellow",
            "birth_year": "41.9BBY",
            "gender": "male",
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ],
            "species": [],
            "vehicles": [],
            "starships": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/13/"
            ],
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:18:20.704000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.313000Z",
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/4/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Leia Organa",
            "height": "150",
            "mass": "49",
            "hair_color": "brown",
            "skin_color": "light",
            "eye_color": "brown",
            "birth_year": "19BBY",
            "gender": "female",
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/2/",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ],
            "species": [],
            "vehicles": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/"
            ],
            "starships": [],
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:20:09.791000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.315000Z",
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/5/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Owen Lars",
            "height": "178",
            "mass": "120",
            "hair_color": "brown, grey",
            "skin_color": "light",
            "eye_color": "blue",
            "birth_year": "52BBY",
            "gender": "male",
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ],
            "species": [],
            "vehicles": [],
            "starships": [],
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:52:14.024000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.317000Z",
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/6/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Beru Whitesun lars",
            "height": "165",
            "mass": "75",
            "hair_color": "brown",
            "skin_color": "light",
            "eye_color": "blue",
            "birth_year": "47BBY",
            "gender": "female",
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ],
            "species": [],
            "vehicles": [],
            "starships": [],
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:53:41.121000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.319000Z",
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/7/"
        },
        {
            "name": "R5-D4",
            "height": "97",
            "mass": "32",
            "hair_color": "n/a",
            "skin_color": "white, red",
            "eye_color": "red",
            "birth_year": "unknown",
            "gender": "n/a",
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/"
            ],
            "species": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/species/2/"
            ],
            "vehicles": [],
            "starships": [],
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:57:50.959000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.321000Z",
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/8/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Biggs Darklighter",
            "height": "183",
            "mass": "84",
            "hair_color": "black",
            "skin_color": "light",
            "eye_color": "brown",
            "birth_year": "24BBY",
            "gender": "male",
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/"
            ],
            "species": [],
            "vehicles": [],
            "starships": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/12/"
            ],
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:59:50.509000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.323000Z",
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/9/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
            "height": "182",
            "mass": "77",
            "hair_color": "auburn, white",
            "skin_color": "fair",
            "eye_color": "blue-gray",
            "birth_year": "57BBY",
            "gender": "male",
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/20/",
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/4/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ],
            "species": [],
            "vehicles": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/38/"
            ],
            "starships": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/48/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/59/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/64/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/65/",
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/74/"
            ],
            "created": "2014-12-10T16:16:29.192000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.325000Z",
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/10/"
        }
    ]
}
```

On my console.log I first get two lines 'undefined' and then get the data I want (the results array).

In my component the {data["count"]} renders after a while, but if I try to get deeper in the data structure (e.g. get the name value of the first item of the results array) I get 'Cannot read properties of undefined'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does calling react setState method not mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here. First of all, the initial state type is not correct. The API call does not return an array, but it returns an object that has a key called `results` that has an array as corresponding value.

```
{count: 82, next: "https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2", previous: null, results: Array(10)}
```

I would suggest setting your initial state as undefined, rather than an empty array.

You can add an 'undefined guard' to make sure that you're only rendering something when you are certain that you have data. You could wait until data is no longer undefined and then map over the results to do something with the result.

```
{ data && data.results.map()}
```

Please have a look at this working [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetching-swapi-0g7i2q). For convenience, I have added TypeScript which improves the developer experience, but this is not required. I have added also an example without TypeScript.

Comment: Adding an undefined guard did help, I used `{!isLoading && data.map()}`

Answer (score 0):

It's because when your component get's loaded for the 1st time your data was not fetched yet. and useEffect is not the first function that actually runs.
you can read about useEffect's timing.

so the event timeline is like this, your People() component runs, data is an empty array. data['count'] is undefined. useEffect runs. fetches the data, then sets data. then it will trigger a re-render but Dom is not updated yet. so what you see is still an empty data array. After that moment everything gets updated. so then you don't see undefined anymore.

When you are fetching async data, your data will be always empty(unless you define an initial data/object etc.)